# Preventing a C# subclass from overwriting a method

Tags: c#, object, inheritance

Say I have an abstract parent class called "Parent" that implements a method called "DisplayTitle".  I want this method to be the same for each subclass that inherits "Parent" - I would like a compile error if a subclass attempts to implement their own "DisplayTitle" method.  How can I accomplish this in C#.  I believe in Java, I'd just mark the method as "final", but I can't seem to find an alternative in C#.  I've been messing around with "sealed" and "override", but I can't get the behavior that I'm looking for.

For example, in this code:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
  class Parent
  {
      public void DisplayTitle() { Console.WriteLine("Parent's Title"); }
  }

  class ChildSubclass : Parent
  {
      public void DisplayTitle() { Console.WriteLine("Child's Own Implementation of Title"); 
  }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ChildSubclass myChild = new ChildSubclass();
        myChild.DisplayTitle();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
}
```

I'd like to receive a compile error saying that the "ChildSubClass" can't override "DisplayTitle".  I currently get a warning - but it seems like this is something that I should be able to do and I don't know the proper attributes to label the method.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> How can I accomplish this in C#. I believe in Java, I'd just mark the method as "final", but I can't seem to find an alternative in C#.

The rough equivalent is `sealed` in C#, but you normally only need it for virtual methods - and your `DisplayTitle` method isn't virtual.

It's important to note that `ChildSubclass` *isn't* overriding `DisplayTitle` - it's *hiding* it. Any code which only uses references to `Parent` won't end up calling that implementation.

Note that with the code as-is, you should get a compile-time warning advising you to add the `new` modifier to the method in `ChildSubclass`:

```
public new void DisplayTitle() { ... }
```

You can't *stop* derived classes from hiding existing methods, other than by sealing the class itself to prevent the creation of a derived class entirely... but callers which don't use the derived type directly won't care.

What's your *real* concern here? Accidental misuse, or deliberate problems?

EDIT: Note that the warning for your sample code would be something like:

```
Test.cs(12,19): warning CS0108:
        'ConsoleApplication1.ChildSubclass.DisplayTitle()' hides inherited
        member 'ConsoleApplication1.Parent.DisplayTitle()'. Use the new keyword
        if hiding was intended.
```

I suggest you turn warnings into errors, and then it's harder to ignore them :)

Comment: I guess my real concern would be accidental misuse.  I have an abstract class in another project that has a "TurnOn" and "TurnOff" method.  Without getting too much into the details - this class is going to be subclasses multiple times to represent real-world objects.  However, all of these devices will be turned on & off the same way.  I just don't want myself or someone else to try to implement their own turn off/turn on commands for individual devices without a warning of some type.

Comment: @user1720817: Well there'd *be* a warning. I'll edit the warning from your sample code into my answer...

Comment: Yep, there is a warning :)  Its just my OCD that makes me want it to be a compile time error.  Thanks for taking the time to write this up!

Comment: +1 for **turn warnings into errors** i did the same in java for handle imports

Answer (score 2):

A derived class cannot override your method, you didn't declare it *virtual*.  Note how that's very different in C# compared to Java, all methods are virtual in Java.  In C# you must explicitly use the keyword.

A derived class can *hide* your method by using the same name again.  This is probably the compile warning you are talking about.  Using the *new* keyword suppresses the warning.  This method does not in any way override your original method, your base class code always calls the original method, not the one in the derived class.

Answer (score 1):

Use the sealed modifier to prevent subclasses from overriding your classes, properties, or methods. What isn't working when you use sealed?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/88c54tsw.aspx

Comment: When I use: "public sealed void DisplayTitle() { Console.WriteLine("Parent's Title"); }" I get a compile error - "'ConsoleApplication1.Parent.DisplayTitle()' cannot be sealed because it is not an override".

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain that what you want is not possible in C# using method modifier keywords.

Sealed only applies when overriding a virtual method in an ancestor class, which then prevent *further* overriding.

Comment: Good point, but the OP wants to prevent hiding the base method by inheriting classes. It's just not possible.

Comment: I guess this seems to be part of what is confusing me the most - why can I seal a method that is inherited, but can't do it in the "base" class?

Comment: @MichaelSallmen, I stated "what you want is not possible", where's your confusion?